# Recorrer un array hasta que aparezca un punto

Tags: php, array

Tengo un texto, por ejemplo: "migato.jpeg"
Lo que quiero hacer es recorrer con un array y que recorra solo hasta el punto y me muestre esto: "migato."

Soy nuevo en esto de PHP y estoy aprendiendo un poco, solo se hacer esto:

```html
$prueba='migato.jpeg';

for($i=0;$i<strlen($prueba);$i++){
    
    echo $prueba[$i];
}
```

Disculpen la pregunta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma rapida seria añadir la condicion de salida (o de permanencia) en el bucle. Por ejemplo, podrias hacer:

```
$prueba='migato.jpeg';

for($i=0;$i<strlen($prueba);$i++){
    if($prueba[$i] == '.') 
        break;

    echo $prueba[$i];
}
```

Con esto, cuando se verifica que el caracter en el que se encuentra el indice es un `.`, se sale fuera del bucle.

Otra forma seria:

```
$prueba='migato.jpeg';

for($i=0;$i<strlen($prueba) && ($prueba[$i] != '.');$i++){
    echo $prueba[$i];
}
```

En este caso, hemos añadido como condicion de permanecia en el bucle, que el caracter actual sea `distinto` de .

Por supuesto, puedes utilizar herramientas ya mas "avanzadas". En tu caso, se ve que es un archivo,

Comment: Tengo otra duda que me acaba de ocurrir ahora, como puedo sacar la variable de $prueba fuera del for? Con el texto obtenido de $prueba[$i]. Perdona por molestar.

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción sería realizarlo a través de la función `explode()`, que te permite convertir el `string` en un `array` troceado a través de un caracter delimitador.

```
$archivo = 'migato.jpeg';

$nombre = explode('.', $archivo)[0];
$extension = explode('.', $archivo)[1];

echo '<p><strong>Nombre del archivo:</strong> ' . $nombre . '</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Extensión del archivo:</strong> ' . $extension . '</p>';
```

Así, de manera sencilla podrías tener el nombre del archivo separado de la extensión, por ejemplo.

**Referencia:** [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Yo te propongo otra solución que si funciona en todos los casos, como estás empezando me gustaría que tengas siempre en mente que cuando buscas la solución a un problema intentes pensar una que se cumpla en la mayoría (o todos) los casos.

Los algoritmos presentados ninguno lo hace y puedo demostrarlo en un ejemplo simple:

**nombre del archivo:** mi.gato.jpeg

El punto en todos los sistemas operativos (creo) es aceptado como parte del nombre de un fichero, con este nombre todo lo descrito acá da un resultado incorrecto.

Para resolver esto de mejor forma hay que pensar que condición se cumple siempre en todos los archivos, en nuestro caso es que siempre la extensión será lo que siga al ÚLTIMO punto del nombre de archivo.

Así te propongo dos soluciones:

**Con recorrido explícito:**

```
$archivo = 'mi.gato.jpeg';
$nombre = '';
$extension = '';

for($i=strlen($prueba);$i>0;$i--){

    if ($prueba[i]=='.'){
        $nombre = substr($prueba, 0, i-1);
        $extension = substr($prueba, i+1, strlen($prueba));
        break;
    }    
}
```

**Explicación:** Se recorre el nombre de archivo del último elemento al primero buscando el primer punto, si lo encuentra, divide la cadena en dos tomando como centro el carácter encontrado.

**Sin recorrido explícito:**

```
$archivo = 'mi.gato.jpeg';
$fileParts = explode('.', $archivo);
$extension = array_pop($fileParts);
$nombre = implode('.',$fileParts);
```

**Explicación:** Primero se divide el archivo separando por el carácter punto, luego se quita el último elemento que será si o si la extensión y por último se une las partes restantes usando como separador el punto para dejar el nombre como al inicio.

Se puede hacer de muchas otras formas, pero revisa de hacerlo usando **expresiones regulares** que es más interesante que la solución que te detallé.